# Determining if langauge is regular using pumping lemma

Tags: computer-science, automata, pumping-lemma

I have language

$L =\{ a^{3i} : i \in N_{0}\}$

if we choose sentence $a^{3p}$

We can decompose it such as

$x = a^{k}$  where k >= 0

$y = a^{l}$ where l >= 1

$z = a^{m}a^{3p-p}$ where m >= 0 ; k + l <= p ; k + l + m = p;

If we choose i = 2 we recieve

$a^{k}a^{2l}a^{m}a^{3p-p}$

which is $a^{3p+l}$ and we have to find that $3p + l \%  3 = 0$ but this is can be true only when p >= 3 , otherwise such case cannot occur , how to determine if this is regular or not?

Comment: If you could produce a finite automaton which accepts all and only strings in your language then you would have shown that the language is regular. Could you do that? Hint: a 3-state FA will do it.

Comment: **Rick Decker**’s hint is one easy way to show that $L$ is regular. Another is to find a regular expression that matches $L$; yet another is to find a regular grammar that generates $L$. Neither of these is at all difficult if you’ve been exposed to the basics of regular expressions and regular grammars.

Comment: Here is some good intuition: FSMs can keep track of parity, but they cannot count. Here, it is easy to see that a FSM can keep track of the number of $a$'s modulo $3$, but not the total number of $a$'s. Now note that the Pumping Lemma for Regular Languages is a necessary condition- if a language $L$ is regular, it satisfies the Pumping Lemma for Regular Languages. The converse is not true- there are non-regular languages that satisfy the Pumping Lemma for Regular Languages.